# NameError: name 'install' is not defined

Tags: python, installation, package

I'm trying to use this code

```
install.packages("rgl", repos = "http://cran.rstudio.com/")
install.packages("ConsRank", repos = "http://cran.rstudio.com/")
library("ConsRank")
```

After installing some packages shows following error:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-b36284337772> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 install.packages("rgl", repos = "http://cran.rstudio.com/")
      2 install.packages("ConsRank", repos = "http://cran.rstudio.com/")
      3 library("ConsRank")
NameError: name 'install' is not defined
```

I'm trying to use this code

```
install.packages("rgl", repos = "http://cran.rstudio.com/")
install.packages("ConsRank", repos = "http://cran.rstudio.com/")
library("ConsRank")
```

Comment: `install.packages()` is an R function that you are trying to use in python.